# What does 'adb remount' do? When is it useful?

Tags: android, adb

Should `adb remount` always be run before `adb push`? What does `adb remount` actually do?

Comment: @bukko, I couldn't find the full answer on google, weirdly. And BTW, my best friend is Stackoverflow :)

Comment: I had to upvote that :)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`adb remount` put `/system` partition in writable mode. By default `/system` is only readable.
It could only be done on rooted device.

It must be done before pushing file on `/system` partition.

`adb remount` corresponding to:

```
adb shell mount -o rw,remount,rw /system
```

Comment: great answer with no extra fat! 10x!

Comment: I had success with   adb shell mount -o rw,remount /system   (note the missing ,rw)