# adb remount failed: Cannot use remount when a checkpoint is in progress

Tags: android, windows-10, adb

I am trying to do an adb remount but it keeps failing due to:
Cannot use remount when a checkpoint is in progress.

I have tried un/reinstalling adb, even tried with a different phone. Just seeing this on one particular computer.

Have tried Googling the answer but haven't seen any relevant posts, any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/28961646/150978 - adb remount requires a rooted device and I assume and adb deamon that does not root permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/fs_mgr/fs_mgr_remount.cpp#176

One useful solution should be:

```
# in device
vdc checkpoint commitChanges
# outside device
adb shell vdc checkpoint commitChanges
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that the problem is localised to a single computer, I recommend restarting the PC.

Comment: You meant this as a "Thanks", which would be considered "not an answer" and deleted. I turned it into an answer. But in order to get it perceived as a helpful answer you would need to [edit] according to [answer]. - Or delete it.